# why game center only works with sand box?

Tags: ios, sandbox, game-center, sprite-kit

I'm trying to enable Game Center for my game built with SpriteKit, by using the tutorial of Ray Wenderlich here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3276/game-center-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-part-12
So after creating the GCHelper.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>

@interface GCHelper : NSObject {
    BOOL gameCenterAvailable;
    BOOL userAuthenticated;
}

@property (assign, readonly) BOOL gameCenterAvailable;

+ (GCHelper *)sharedInstance;
- (void)authenticateLocalUser;

@end
```

and the GCHelper.m

```
#import "GCHelper.h"

@implementation GCHelper

@synthesize gameCenterAvailable;

#pragma mark Initialization

static GCHelper *sharedHelper = nil;
+ (GCHelper *) sharedInstance {
    if (!sharedHelper) {
        sharedHelper = [[GCHelper alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedHelper;
}

- (BOOL)isGameCenterAvailable {
    // check for presence of GKLocalPlayer API
    Class gcClass = (NSClassFromString(@"GKLocalPlayer"));

    // check if the device is running iOS 4.1 or later
    NSString *reqSysVer = @"4.1";
    NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    BOOL osVersionSupported = ([currSysVer compare:reqSysVer
                                           options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending);

    return (gcClass && osVersionSupported);
}

- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        gameCenterAvailable = [self isGameCenterAvailable];
        if (gameCenterAvailable) {
            NSNotificationCenter *nc =
            [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
            [nc addObserver:self
                   selector:@selector(authenticationChanged)
                       name:GKPlayerAuthenticationDidChangeNotificationName
                     object:nil];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)authenticationChanged {

    if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].isAuthenticated && !userAuthenticated) {
        NSLog(@"Authentication changed: player authenticated.");
        userAuthenticated = TRUE;
    } else if (![GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].isAuthenticated && userAuthenticated) {
        NSLog(@"Authentication changed: player not authenticated");
        userAuthenticated = FALSE;
    }

}

- (void)authenticateLocalUser {

    if (!gameCenterAvailable) return;

    NSLog(@"Authenticating local user...");
    if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated == NO) {
        [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:nil];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Already authenticated!");
    }
}

@end
```

I linked the sharedinstance to my AppDelegate in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
[GCHelper sharedInstance] authenticateLocalUser];
```

So when the game launches I can login in by using my apple id account, seems like I should always log in to GC from the game, when I want the game to know if I'm already logged in or not. and second, when I log in, I'm logged in as Sand Box, what is pretty annoying because when I change game, in the other games I'm not using the sandbox account. Any idea what can be making this mess?

Answer (score 0):

Sandbox account appears to be using because you use Developer's Provisioning Profile to build your app.

Comment: No, actually I'm using none as Provisioning Profile. And I tried with all Profiles. The Game Center in Capabilities is enabled, and stills no authenticating the local user. Any other idea?

Comment: Mine is doing the same thing